# Question about Logic Level MOSFET's

Tags: mosfet, logic-level

In this schematic i thought i was connecting the 19v in to Q1 the source of the MOSFET and continue out the drain. however in eagle the default connection shows it supposed to connect the 19v in to the drain and continuing out the source but that cant be right can it? should i ignore what eagle says and connect it the way i think it should?
[image: Imgage]

Comment: What do you mean the "default" connection?  Also it looks like you may not have connected to the gates at all but just ended a wire in the middle of the the symbol.  Regardless of what you think the software is suggesting (I find the idea that it is suggesting anything quite doubtful) you should check the board (ratsnest and again before ordering) against the data sheet to verify that the actual signals you want are connected to the actually appropriate pins on the physical device you have chosen.

Comment: Sorry, when designing the pcb in eagle it wants to put the trace at the drain instead of the source of the mosfet

Comment: Also please replace that huge, zoomed out image with one that clearly illustrates your concern by showing just a single FET with your uncertainty labeled or annotated.

Comment: "it wants to put the trace at the drain instead of the source of the mosfet" no, there is no such intention in the software.  Whatever is going on, you are misinterpreting the intent.  You could have any sort of issue, from a symbol with some wiring points off-grid, to a symbol that needs to be mirrored to fit how you want to draw...

Comment: This is what it is doing, according to the spec sheet it is suggesting that i connect it to the drain instead of source![image](http://i.imgur.com/JdveWro.png)

Comment: Oh, you mean the board ratsnest, you should have said so.  That will suggest (very nearly "require") that you make the connections you made in the schematic.  If those are not what you want, then either your schematic is wrong, or the mapping of schematic pins to package pins does not match the part you intend to use.  You should double check this from one end of the process through to the other, including opening and examining the library part.

Comment: In a N fet, the source is the more negative terminal (e.g. ground as opposed to vcc), in P fets, this is reversed and the source should go to the most positive rail, don't get too hung up on the nomenclature as the names don't necessarily indicate polarity or current flow (in an npn transistor, the emitter goes to ground... )

Comment: Ok thank you ill wire it the way the rats nets says to, ill just make 2 different boards just in case, no sense in having to wait another week or so if it does not work

Comment: Tom repost as answer so i can give you credit

Comment: No, do not blindly wire it the way the rats nest suggests **spend time to check your connections in the schematic, library part pin assignments, and board**.  There should be no uncertainty whatsoever.

Comment: This looks a lot like a basic cell-phone charger, but does not make sense. Vcc and "Battery" should not connect together. Normally Q1 and Q2 select the source of power for the charger IC. Q3 is to battery power the device but should connect to Q2 drain so the current sense works. Look at the recent question I answered "What is the purpose of mosfets in this schematic"?

Comment: This is a charge circuit meant for a laptop or in my case a tablet pc i used the texas instruments schematic of this chip for reference. what it should do is allow for the computer to be powered from the adapter while the battery charges but when the adapter is unplugged the battery is used for power

Comment: and i'll accept any advice you have to give as im new to all this, im forcing myself to work with hard stuff so everything else seems  simple sure it will take me longer but im learning alot

Comment: I applaud diving right into the hard stuff, but you might find this project a bit much for a newbie. There are a lot of basic concepts here that all need to work in concert for this circuit to function correctly. I don't want to discourage you, but prepare for a very steep learning curve with this project.

Comment: yes that is why i chose a cheap pcb maker that allows for "shotgun engineering" so i can make multiple pcb's at once to find out what ones work and which do not. i find the best way to learn is by doing something that need is needed as to not deter me from it

Comment: The problem with that approach is that your necessary number of trials grows rapidly from the *combination* of possible errors.  It's really best to try to eliminate the doubts before ordering, and save the variety for a situation where you might want to try parts in irreconcilable footprints for a given role (though you can usually just support both on the same board).

Answer (score 2):

Eagle doesn't have 'default' connections - it only puts wires where *you* tell it! If you want to connect the 19V input to Q1's Source then you need to draw it that way.

Perhaps you are confused about where to terminate the wires. The connection points are the ends of the pins (short red 'wires') projecting out from the component. If you are not sure whether the wires have joined to the correct places then drag the component around and you should see where the wires are attached to it (or not).

In your schematic there is no connection to the Gate of Q1. Drag the FET around and you will see that the wire you think is going to the Gate is actually not terminated. It should be going to the pin on the lower right of the symbol (circled in red below).

[image]

To check for other drawing mistakes like this you can use the 'ERC' tool. Don't be surprised to see a long list of errors!

Note that wiring errors will only be flagged if they break Eagle's design rules, even if the circuit doesn't make sense. So it is possible to (for example) have two grounds shorting out a component and Eagle won't complain.

> the default connection shows it supposed to connect the 19v in to the
>   drain and continuing out the source but that cant be right can it?

It looks right to me, as Q1 and Q2 appear to be wired 'back to back' to prevent back-feeding from the output to the input. How is it connected in your reference design?

Comment: its the same as it is in the reference design

Comment: Good point about the ERC tool; rather like lint with C, this tool should be run frequently on a schematic to keep errors (and warnings which may point to an error) in check. A large design that only runs ERC after supposed completion is a cleansing of the stables I would not wish upon anyone.